# Chrome 11 bug in parsing CSS rules

Tags: css, debugging, google-chrome, bug-tracking

I have this slider:

[image]

And it works like a charm in almost all browsers (Firefox, Opera, Safari, and even the designer-killer browser, IE). But in Chrome 11 (I have to support this version of Chrome) and lower versions the right button falls down. I was tracking to see why it behaves so, and I came across something really interesting, but at the same time annoying. For my left and right buttons, I have a very simple CSS rules:

```
#rightBtn
{
    background: url(/images/rightBtn.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    width: 56px;
    height: 56px;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: -60px;
}

#leftBtn
{
    background: url(/images/leftBtn.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    width: 56px;
    height: 56px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: -60px;
}

#leftBtn:hover, #rightBtn:hover
{
    background-position: 0px -56px;
}

.definitionContent
{
    width: 820px;
    height: 365px;
    float: left;
}
```

But, when I inspected rightBtn through Chrome 11's developer toolbar, look what I've found:

[image]

It seems that Chromes parser mixes CSS rules of the next selector (`.definitionContent`) with the hover rules of my button. Anyone got any idea?

Comment: can you please create a fiddle example of it (http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: No, I'm sorry. It's a portion of a complicated design. I can't create the fiddle :)

Comment: Does this work in Chrome 12? If so it's obviously a bug that was fixed, and since 12 is the latest stable release it's safe to assume almost everyone will have been upgraded.

Comment: Might be helpful to see the HTML for the slider as well.

Comment: The downvote trolls are about again... Upvoted to counter; this is a nice question.

Comment: Yeah @Josh, woks like a charm in Chrome 12. I think Chrome 11 has many bugs. Because it crashes many times, and fails to reload images from cache.

Comment: Well, after almost 3 hours of struggling with this problem with a team of 4 members and testing other browsers (even IE7), I can officially announce that Google Chrome 11 has a bug in it's CSS parser. :). We cancelled support for version 11. Version 12 is in action now. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 0):

you can try changing the order of the html( http://jsfiddle.net/PjFba/1/ ):

```
<div class="definitionContent">
    <div id="leftBtn"></div>

    <div id="rightBtn"></div>
</div>
```