# Inline CSS style "visibility" set to "visible" but computed style is "hidden". Why?

Tags: css, google-chrome, visibility

I have explicitly specified an element as "visibility: visible" yet it doesn't display in Chrome.  Using Chrome's Developer Tools, I can see the inline style specified, but the "Computed Style" shows "visibility: hidden".

Well that explains why it's not displaying in Chrome, but I don't understand what's causing Chrome to compute the visibility to be hidden.  (Appears to work correctly in all other browsers.)

I have also inspected all parent elements and all either do not mention visibility or specify it to be visible.

I executed the following JavaScript command directly, via the Developer Tools console, to no avail (computed visibility remained "hidden"):

```
document.getElementById("c_311").style.visibility="visible"
```

See screenshot here:  http://oi52.tinypic.com/ezrdcy.jpg

Comment: It would help to have access to a working reproduction of this.

Comment: It's possible. Are there any CSS stylesheets with `!important` on them?

Comment: There are no stylesheets used at all.

Comment: A screenshot is not a working reproduction.  Post your html somewhere, or your chances of getting an answer are very low.

Comment: I would have posted the HTML but the documented is generated dynamically in a certain order.  If the HTML is then copied and then reloaded (statically), everything works fine.  Thus, the problem is not reproduceable via static HTML, only when constructed dynamically (which requires a server infrastructure which I cannot make available).

Answer (score 2):

I know this is late, but I had the same issue lately, with Chrome 23. It seems like the secret is to also set the display property, like so:

```
domElem.style.visibility = 'visible';
domElem.style.display = 'block';//this is needed mainly for Chrome
```

and, to hide:

```
domElem.style.visibility = 'hidden';
domElem.style.display = 'none';//this is needed mainly for Chrome
```

It seems like Chrome uses a computed setting for visibility. IE and FF will hide or show the element when 'visibility' is set, regardless of 'display' property.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Chrome are you using? It has some bugs on version 11. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6640835/chrome-11-bug-in-parsing-css-rules) post.

Comment: Also tested with Chrome 14.0.814.0 canary.  Same results.